# Как привести к нижнему регистру буквы, перед которыми есть '-'?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

На входе: Test-Some-Strings-12more
На выходе: Test-some-strings-12more

Comment: было бы удобно так, но не в js https://regex101.com/r/4StbmV/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без регулярных выражений

```js
const str = 'Test-Some-Strings-12more'
const res = [...str].map((item, index) =>
  str[index -1] === '-'
    ? item.toLowerCase()
    : item
  ).join('')
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = "Test-Some-Strings-12more";
let result = str.replace(/-\w/gm, str => str.toLowerCase());
console.log(result);
```

Comment: что-то вы переборщили, `/-\w/gm` и `s => s.toLowerCase()` будет достаточно ведь

Comment: @teran Спасибо за замечание, Вы правы. Изначально я почему то подумал, что это должно касаться только 1-ой буквы.

Comment: только первой и должно, `*` у вас лишняя просто